# wondering if sed or awk can reorder using line number

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I currently have a text file that starts like this,

```
ATOM    277  N   DOPC    3       2.637   5.546  17.667  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    278  C12 DOPC    3       2.869   5.398  19.176  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    279 H12A DOPC    3       3.729   6.005  19.418  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    280 H12B DOPC    3       3.176   4.394  19.427  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    281  C13 DOPC    3       1.352   4.873  17.275  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    282 H13A DOPC    3       1.380   5.091  16.217  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    283 H13B DOPC    3       1.415   3.810  17.452  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    284 H13C DOPC    3       0.491   5.261  17.799  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    285  C14 DOPC    3       3.791   4.845  16.976  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    286 H14A DOPC    3       4.692   4.989  17.554  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    287 H14B DOPC    3       3.563   3.790  17.025  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    288 H14C DOPC    3       3.875   5.097  15.930  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    289  C15 DOPC    3       2.627   6.991  17.324  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    290 H15A DOPC    3       1.812   7.530  17.785  1.00  0.00      MEMB
.
.
```

I'm wondering if there is any way using sed or awk to reorder the lines so that the ordering goes from [1,2,3...14...] to [1,2,5,9,13,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,14...] just by simply using their unique line number?

Here is the desired output,

```
ATOM    277  N   DOPC    3       2.637   5.546  17.667  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    278  C12 DOPC    3       2.869   5.398  19.176  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    281  C13 DOPC    3       1.352   4.873  17.275  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    285  C14 DOPC    3       3.791   4.845  16.976  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    289  C15 DOPC    3       2.627   6.991  17.324  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    279 H12A DOPC    3       3.729   6.005  19.418  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    280 H12B DOPC    3       3.176   4.394  19.427  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    284 H13C DOPC    3       0.491   5.261  17.799  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    286 H14A DOPC    3       4.692   4.989  17.554  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    287 H14B DOPC    3       3.563   3.790  17.025  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    288 H14C DOPC    3       3.875   5.097  15.930  1.00  0.00      MEMB
ATOM    290 H15A DOPC    3       1.812   7.530  17.785  1.00  0.00      MEMB
.
.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear, please do add logic by which you want to get your output. Also add your efforts which is highly encouraged on SO along with sample of output in CODE TAGS in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'push @a, $_; END { print $a[$_-1] for ( 1,2,5,9,13,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14, 15..($#a+1) ); }' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.

`push @a, $_;` : Add to the array `@a` (which is empty initially) the current line as the next element.
`$#a` : The index of the last element of the array `@a`.
`END { ... }` : After all input lines have been read, execute the code inside the block. Here, print the lines in the specified order.

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk -v order="1,2,5,9,13,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14" '{
    a[NR]=$0              # hash records to a with NR as index
}
END { 
    n=split(order,o,/,/)  # split the given order to a mapping
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {   # iterate the map indexes
        print a[o[i]]     # output
        # delete a[o[i]]  # uncomment these
    }
    # for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)  # to print any leftovers
    #     if(i in a)      # that were not in the order list
    #         print a[i]
}' file
```

Comment: Hmm, it produces faulty output. Oh yeah, your order has 13 twice.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry the additional 13 is a typo. I have corrected this, sorry!